# Only one sent items appear in Blackberry Hub

Tags: exchange, blackberry, activesync

One of my users is having issues with her email account since we updated her Blackberry Q10 to BB 10.2.

When we go onto the Blackberry Hub, her inbox is fine, but only the very latest sent email shows up. Whenever a new email is sent, it replaces that one. This was not an issue before the update.

She is connected using ActiveSync on an Exchange 2010 server.